# Vue.js Redirected when going from to via a navigation guard

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a protected route that the user get's access to once he has logged in. What I want to do is to redirect him to the home page once he clicks on a div, currently It doesn't work, because I get these two errors:

```
Error: Redirected when going from "/captables" to "/home" via a navigation guard.
```

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

What am I doing wrong to cause this errors and how can I fix them?

Here is my index.js:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
                                                
import Multibaas from '../components/MultibaasExample.vue'
Vue.use(Router)

const router =  new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/unauthorized',
      name: 'Unauthorized',
      component: Unauthorized
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      component: NotFound,
      name: 'NotFound',
    },
    {
      path: '/multibaas',
      name: 'Multibaas',
      component: Multibaas
    },
    {
      path: '/captables',
      name: 'CapTables',
      component: CapTables,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      },
    },
  ],
  mode: 'history'
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
 const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
 const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)

 if(requiresAuth && !currentUser) next('/')
   else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser) next('home')
   else next()
});

export default router
```

I tried to change the next to `router push` but that didn't do much.

and here is my html:

```
      <md-button class="view-captable-btn" v-for="item in capTables" :key="item.contractAddress" 
        @click="navigateAway"> 
        <p>{{item.label}}</p>
        <p class="contract-address-p"> {{item.contractAddress}}</p>
       </md-button>
```

and my redirection function:

```
navigateAway() {
        this.$router.push('/home')
      }
```

Here is `console.log` stack:

```
Error: Redirected when going from "/captables" to "/home" via a navigation guard.
    at createRouterError (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2008)
    at createNavigationRedirectedError (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1967)
    at eval (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2314)
    at eval (index.js?a18c:58)
    at iterator (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2300)
    at step (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1947)
    at step (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1951)
    at runQueue (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1955)
    at HTML5History.confirmTransition (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2330)
    at HTML5History.transitionTo (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2203)
```

Comment: Put your `*` route last. See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#catch-all-404-not-found-route

Comment: I just did that and I still get the same errors

Comment: Can you create a stackbiltz example

Comment: I updated my question with the console.log result

Comment: Try adding `/` (slash) before `home` when calling `next` -> `else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser) next('/home')`

Comment: tried that, stiill same errors